# Functionally comparing data sets to each other once with Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, functional-programming, dataset, comparison

After over a year of mental wrangling, I finally understand Haskell well enough to consider it my primary language for the majority of my general programming needs. I absolutely love it.

But I still struggle with doing very specific operations in a functional way.

A simplified example:

```
Set = [("Bob", 10), ("Megan", 7), ("Frank", 2), ("Jane", 11)]
```

I'd like to compare these entries to each other. With a language like C or Python, I'd probably create some complicated loop, but I'm not sure which approach (map, fold, list comprehension?) would be best or most efficient with a functional language.

Here's a sample of the code I started working on:

```
run xs = [ someAlgorithm (snd x) (snd y) | x <- xs, y <- xs, x /= y ]
```

The predicate keeps the list comprehension from comparing entries with themselves, but the function isn't very efficient because it compares entries that have already been compared. For example. It'll compare Bob with Megan, and then compare Megan with Bob.

Any advice on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say that you want to compare them, but not what you want to do with the result from the comparison. From your sample it seems that you want to look at every choice of two different elements from a list. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, but not the "reverse" choice. I'd like to compare Bob with Megan, Bob with Frank, Bob with Jane, and then Megan with Frank, Megan with Jane, and then Frank with Jane (I think that covers all combinations). This looks like something that could be done with fold, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an ordering on your data type, you can just use `x < y` instead of `x /= y`.

Another approach is to use `tails` to avoid comparing elements in the same position:

```
[ ... | (x:ys) <- tails xs, y <- ys]
```

This has the effect of only picking items `y` that occur after `x` in the original list. If your list contains duplicates, you'll want to combine this with the explicit filtering from before.

Comment: OP appears to want to look at all pairs, ignoring order, so I don't think sorting helps--it seems like a necessarily n**2 problem. +1 for the tails suggestion though, which I think is the right answer.

Comment: @JameySharp: Yes, I had a bit of a brain fart on that one. Already removed that part :)

Comment: Such a concise solution! Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: One should note that it is *not* an error but rather intentional that the pattern `(x:ys) <- tails xs` will fail when it hits the last element of `tails xs`, which is `[]`. In list comprehensions, pattern match failures are not errors but cause the element to be skipped.